# Button color change when button pressed

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I have been trying over an hour to make a `button`'s color change when I click the button.

Here is my "mybutton.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#c4161616"
        android:endColor="#c4161616"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="5px"
        android:color="#00FF00" />
</shape>
```

Now the Button looks like this:

[image]

And when the button gets pressed it should look like this:

[image]

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#c4161616"
    android:endColor="#c4565656"
    android:angle="270" />
```

I'm a beginner in Android and XML. Can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: you need a selector to do this. define onfocus state then give it as background to the button. it will work like a charm. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bro try this:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```